# Reload a table to restore its structure or Reload the form containing the table in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have **jsp** page containing a `table` inside a `form`. The form contains basic fields like `label` for *name of the field* and `<input>` for the user to *enter details*. I have used the `table` just to arrange the contents of the form to look neat.

I have a thinking like I can use some `fields` of the `form` for another process but not all of it just to reduce the code. So, I have used two `radio` buttons for selecting which one of the processes should be done. I had the contents of the `form` unchanged for the first process. For the second process, I will be deleting two rows of the same `form` using the **code below**, since I don't need it for the second process.

```
 document.getElementById("form").deleteRow(1);
 document.getElementById("form").deleteRow(0);
```

I have used **AJAX** for moving from one process to another in order to avoid refreshing the whole page.

When the both the processes are done once by switching using radio buttons everything works fine. When the processes are repeated for the second time the `rows` of the `table` get decreased by two each time I switch between the processes leading to an empty `form` at a point.

I can understand why it is happening. It is because of the deleting the rows where its indexes are reset, which leads to an empty form at a point.

I think the solution might be either the rows of the `table` should be restored after the process is done or the form(only that particular form) in jsp page should be reloaded.

I do not want to insert the rows because I am not getting the contents of the table dynamically(i.e from the database). I have the contents in jsp.

Any Suggestions???